# Скрипт для запуска на странице

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.  Как на открытом в браузере  сайте отобрать элементы?  К примеру добавить кнопку перед картинкой что скачать её

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все очень просто. Берете находите картинку, находите контейнер который держит эту картинку, потом присобачиваете эти 2 кнопки через document.createElement(), а на кнопки накладываете свои эвенты с нужными функциями. Ну а стили меняйте как вам хочется, главное найти нужные элемент.

Задача простая и похоже она от работодателя, если вы не можете справиться с такой самостоятельно, то лучше вообще за такую работу не браться, а подготовиться к этому и через несколько месяцев обратиться опять.

Вот список того, что вам может пригодиться.

- [Статья о том как работать с dev
  tools](http://frontender.info/chrome-developer-tools/)
- [Основы javascript (если вы их не
  знаете)](http://learn.javascript.ru/first-steps)
- [Навигация по дом
  элементом](http://learn.javascript.ru/traversing-dom)
- [Поиск dom
  элементов](http://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom)
- [Работа со стилями через
  js](http://learn.javascript.ru/styles-and-classes)
- [Добавление или удаление элементов в
  dom](http://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document)
- [Введение в браузерные события
  (эвенты)](http://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events)
- [Открытие вкладок через
  js](http://learn.javascript.ru/window-methods)